# Reading double from a file with system call read

Tags: c

```
double a[5];
for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
    read(fd, &a[i], sizeof(double));
}
```

When I print the content of the array, it shows me only zeros. How can I read double numbers from a text file without using `fscanf`?

File.txt

```
2.00 5.11 6.90 3.4 8.7
```

If I read char by char until the end of line, everything is fine.

Comment: The file has to be binary in order for `read` to work. In other words, if you want to use `read` to get the numbers, then you need to use `write` to put the numbers in the file. Note that storing numbers in a binary file has lots of potential portability problems.

Comment: If you don't want to use `fscanf()`, you'll probably need to read lines of characters (e.g. with `fgets()`) and then parse them (e.g. with `strtod()`).  Since you have a single line, you'll need to read the line and loop using `strtod()`.  If the file contains more than one line, you will have to work harder; the file descriptor I/O primitives don't know what a newline is and don't know how to respect line boundaries.

Comment: You don't have doubles *in* the file. You have real numbers represented as text. You need to *convert.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by others if you don't want to use `fscanf()` then probably you should read all data from file using `read()` and store into *char buffer* and parse upto `whitespace` and then use `strtod()` to convert resultant string into `double`.

Here is the helping solution not complete one

```
 int main() {

            int fd = open("input.txt",O_RDWR | 0664);
            if(fd == -1) {
                    perror("open");
                    return 0;
            }
            /* first find the size of file */
            int size = lseek(fd,0,2);
            printf("size of file : %d \n",size);
            lseek(fd,0,0);/* again start reading from beginning */
            /* take buffer equal to size of file */
            char *buf = malloc(size * sizeof(char) + 1);
            /* read all at a time using read()*/
            read(fd,buf,size);
            buf[size] = '\0';
            printf("%s\n",buf);
            /* now parse using strtod() */
            double res;
            char new_buf[64]; /* to store each double number read from fil
    e */
            for(int iter = 0,inner_iter = 0;buf[iter] != '\0' ;iter++ ) {
                    if(buf[inner_iter]!=' ' ) {
                            new_buf[inner_iter++] = buf[iter];
                            continue;
                    }
                    else {
                            new_buf[inner_iter] = '\0';
                            res = strtod(new_buf,NULL);
                            printf("%lf\n",res);
                            inner_iter = 0; /* make this variable 0 again */
                    }
            }
            free(buf);
            close(fd);
            return 0;
 }
```

Comment: One last complaint: why are you assuming that the doubles are stored with maximal length of 7 characters? It's ok to do that guess, but at least check that `inner_iter` doesn't exceed 7 before doing `new_buf[inner_iter++] = buf[iter];` If the trickster entered `2.00 5.11 6.90 3.4 8.79999999999999999` you would have a problem.